# Convert Image datatype to Varchar

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column of the image datatype that a piece of software uses to store text for some reason.

I'm trying to pull the data out and convert it to varchar using many examples I've found here.

Currently I have

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), BITS,2)) FROM V_SO_MTL_BINARY
```

The problem is that only converts the first character from the string for some reason. How do I convert from Image to Varchar and not only get the first character.

Comment: You might just need `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)` depending on how the data is originally inserted.

Comment: That was it, post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Of course it was that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just need `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)` depending on how the data is originally inserted.

If it is in fact `nvarchar` then typical ASCII text will have lots of `00` bytes. e.g. `N'Some String'` is stored as `0x53006F006D006500200053007400720069006E006700`

These will be treated as string terminating null characters when casting back to `varchar` hence only seeing the first character.

```
SELECT CAST(0x53006F006D006500200053007400720069006E006700 AS VARCHAR(30))
```

Returns `S`